Measuring LIPO voltage while connected to TP4056 charger
I am building a project where I need to continuously monitor the backup battery voltage. I have the charger circuit built with very common TP4056 and have a MOSFET based switching circuit, that connects the backup battery to the power rail with the external supply goes off. The circuits are like below

Charging Circuit

Power switching circuit

Voltage measurement with ADC
If I tap BATT+ pin (measuring with MCUs ADC), then I'll always read the charging voltage of TP4056. I do need to check the battery health instead (just the battery voltage needs to be measured, if it is present).
